# Why is the undefined function levity-polymorphic when using it with unboxed types?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, representation

I just got finished reading the paper [Levity Polymorphism](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2017/levity/levity-extended.pdf).

I had a question about why [`undefined`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined) can be levity-polymorphic when used as an unboxed type.

First, let's start with some definitions of boxity from the paper:

- **boxed**:

  - A **boxed** value is represented by a pointer into the heap.
  - `Int` and `Bool` are examples of types that have **boxed** values.
- **unboxed**:

  - An **unboxed** value is represented by the value itself (*not* a pointer to the heap).
  - [`Int#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:3) and [`Char#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:2) from the [`GHC.Prim`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html) module are examples of types with **unboxed** values.
  - An **unboxed** value cannot be a thunk.  Function arguments of unboxed types must be passed by value.

The paper follows with some definitions of levity:

- **lifted**:

  - A **lifted** type is one that is lazy.
  - A **lifted** type has on extra element beyond the normal ones, representing a non-terminating computation.
  - For example, the type `Bool` is **lifted**, meaning that there are three different values for `Bool`: `True`, `False`, and `⊥` (bottom).
  - All **lifted** types MUST be **boxed**.
- **unlifted**

  - An **unlifted** type is one that is strict.
  - The element `⊥` does not exist in an **unlifted** type.
  - `Int#` and `Char#` are examples of **unlifted** types.

The paper goes on to explain how GHC 8 provides functionality allowing type variables to have polymorphic levity.

This allows you to write a levity-polymorphic [`undefined`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined) with the following type:

```
undefined :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep). forall (a :: TYPE r). a
```

This says that `undefined` should work for *any* `RuntimeRep`, even unlifted types.

Here is an example of using `undefined` as an unboxed, unlifted `Int#` in GHCi:

```
> :set -XMagicHash
> import GHC.Prim
> import GHC.Exts
> I# (undefined :: Int#)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

---

I've always thought of `undefined` as being the same as `⊥` (bottom).  However, the paper says, "The element `⊥` does not exist in an unlifted type."

What is going on here? Is `undefined` not actually `⊥` when used as an unlifted type?  Am I misunderstanding something about the paper (or boxity or levity)?

Comment: I suppose that `⊥` is any computation that cannot terminate normally, including e.g. infinite loops. OTOH `undefined` is a known _value_ which is checked for at runtime.

Comment: @9000 But the definition of unlifted types is explicitly that they do not have that known value as an inhabitant. I think this question is quite well-motivated, and I myself am curious about the answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I fail to see a contradiction. «The element `⊥` does not exist in an unlifted type»; `undefined` ≠ `⊥`. I also don't think that `I# (undefined :: Int#)` actually "produces" an `undefined` of type `Int#`. I suppose that at the first moment strict evaluation touches an "undefined", it raises an exception, and this is special-cased, as opposed to adding an `undefined` to every type.

Comment: @9000 Hm. `undefined` is synonymous with ⊥ in every discussion of Haskell semantics I know of; why do you believe they are not equal? Or, what equality relation are you using that does not conflate them, and why do you believe that is the equality intended by the discussion in the question above?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I'm looking [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type#Computer_science_applications) which states: «The bottom type is frequently used for the following purposes: To signal that a function or computation diverges; in other words, does not return a result to the caller.» That is, a bottom's meaning may be an infinite loop, a crash, an exit, etc. It therefore _can not_ be returned as a value. This is why it cannot inhabit a type of a strict / unlifted computation; in a lazy computation, it can be deferred.

Comment: I _don't know_ if `undefined` is indeed a value (that is, something that can be strictly computed and returned). I can imagine that it's not; then it can represent the bottom value. But then it also cannot be "instantiated", as the OP tries to do. OTOH if it were a value that can be computed, then it won't be bottom. So I suppose that computation around `undefined` is special-cased in compiler and runtime. It can be cast to any type, but not actually touched, so an attempt to construct in for an unlifted type should fail immediately (this must be easy to check).

Comment: @9000 This is the bottom value, not the bottom type. That said: yes, an infinite loop, a crash, an exit, an exception are all bottom (and semantically identical -- the fact that Haskell occasionally lets you distinguish them is cheating in some ways). `undefined` throws an exception, and is bottom in that way.

Comment: Hence we seem to have an answer: `undefined` may be levity-polymorphic because it's special-cased. It cannot be computed, by definition, so it can take part in any lazy computation as long as it's lazy, but an attempt to construct it for an unlifted type (with which it is  type-compatible) ends with a runtime error, "producing" the bottom value.

Comment: One thing is that a variable (and even the dummy pattern `_`) can never be bound to a bottom value of an unlifted type. Given `f (x :: Int#) = ...`, if I call `f undefined`, execution will never reach the right-hand side. GHC will attempt to evaluate `undefined` *before* calling `f`.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes, because a value of bottom type is basically a crashed (or hung) computation, so the computation will crash (with an exception) before binding.

Comment: Another point: I'm quite confident you actually *can't* write `undefined` with the signature you indicate. Its `HasCallStack` constraint is necessary to satisfy the type checker. That makes it (effectively) a function rather than a value.

Comment: @dfeuer Good point about `HasCallStack`.  I took it out, hoping to make the type signature for `undefined` a little easier to read.  It makes sense that it is actually necessary!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Author of the "Levity Polymorphism" paper here.

First, I want to clear up a few misconceptions stated above:

- `Bool` is indeed a lifted, boxed type. However, it still has only 2 values: `True` and `False`. The expression ⊥ is simply not a value. It's an expression, and a variable can be bound to ⊥, but that doesn't make ⊥ a value. Perhaps a better way of saying this all is that, if `x :: Bool`, then evaluating `x` can lead to three different results: evaluating to `True`, evaluating to `False`, and ⊥. Here, ⊥ represents any computation that doesn't terminate normally, including throwing an exception (which is what `undefined` really does) and looping forever.
- Similar to that last point, `undefined` is not a value. It's an inhabitant of any type, but it's not a value. A value is something that, when evaluated, does nothing -- but `undefined` doesn't meet that specification.
- Depending on how you look at it, ⊥ *can* exist in an unlifted type. For example, take this definition:

  ```
  loop :: () -> Int#
  loop x = loop x
  ```

  This definition is accepted by GHC. Yet `loop ()` is a ⊥ element of the unlifted, unboxed type `Int#`. The difference between an unlifted type and a lifted type in this regard is that there is no way to bind a variable to `loop ()`. Any attempt to do so (like `let z = loop () in ...`) will loop before the variable ever gets bound.

  Note that this is no different than an infinitely recursive function in an unmanaged language, like C.

So, how is it that we allow `undefined` to have an unlifted type? @dfeuer has it right: `undefined` is secretly a function. Its full type signature is `undefined :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep) (a :: TYPE r). HasCallStack => a`, meaning that it's a function, just like `loop`, above. At runtime, it will take the current call stack as a parameter. So, whenever you use `undefined`, you're just calling a function that throws an exception, causing no trouble.

Indeed, when designing levity polymorphism, we struggled with `undefined` for quite some time, with all sorts of shenanigans to make it work out. Then, when we realized that `undefined` had the `HasCallStack` constraint, we saw that we could just dodge the problem entirely. I honestly don't know what we would have done without the seemingly inconsequential user convenience of `HasCallStack`.