# What does type signature for `undefined` mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, undefined, forall, type-signature

I am a beginner in Haskell and I am taken aback by the `undefined` function's type signature.

I expected something more simple, but I found this on Hackage:

```
undefined :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep). forall (a :: TYPE r). HasCallStack => a
```

> A special case of error. It is expected that compilers will recognize this and insert error messages which are more appropriate to the context in which `undefined` appears.

Could you please explain what does this signature mean?

Thanks!

Comment: First off, `undefined` is not a function. But if you're still a beginner, I'd just pretend the type is `undefined :: a`. The rest is advanced magic.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986342/why-is-the-undefined-function-levity-polymorphic-when-using-it-with-unboxed-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318562/what-is-levity-polymorphism

Comment: I see I need to revise my comment: `undefined` is not a function at the language (user) level. However, due to the class constraint `HasCallStack =>` it is implemented as a function internally.

Comment: If you were looking for something like JavaScript's `undefined` or Java's `null`, you probably want to use `Data.Maybe`. A good introduction is http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all regards a beginner needs to know, the signature is simply

```
undefined :: a
```

which means, as always with type variables (i.e. any lowercase letters) that `a` is [universally quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), which can also be made explicit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall #-}
undefined :: forall a. a
```

...or, as I prefer to write it

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall, UnicodeSyntax #-}
undefined :: ∀ a. a
```

The quantification is infered to be over *all types*, i.e. all things with kind `*` (read: “type”, more accurate *the kind of lifted types* – lifted meaning it can be lazy thunk). Therefore, you can use `undefined` in any expression, no matter what type is required.

Now, `undefined` is of course a “partial function” like thing, basically a function which zero arguments which is defined nowhere. (FTR, it's *not* a function, as a function by definition *has* argument[s].)

You'd like to get a *useful* error message when it is actually evaluated, but GHC doesn't by default produce a call stack for everything (for performance reasons), so it used to be the case that the error message was almost completely useless. That's where the [`HasCallStack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html#t:HasCallStack) comes in: that's a constraint which essentially tells the context in which some code might incur `undefined` that it should note the place where it happens, in order for the error message to actually show it up. So,

```
undefined :: ∀ a. HasCallStack => a
```

It's a bit confusing that the `HasCallStack` appears after the `∀ a` – this doesn't really have anything to do with `a` but with the context in which `undefined` will be used. Just, the form of signatures is always

```
Identifier :: Quantifiers. Constraints => Type
```

and `HasCallStack` is a constraint, that's why it appears in the middle. (More often, constraints actually apply to one of the type variables you've quantified over.)

Finally, this `RunTimeRep` stuff is about *levity polymorphism*. I don't really understand that myself, but it's discussed in [Why is the undefined function levity-polymorphic when using it with unboxed types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986342/why-is-the-undefined-function-levity-polymorphic-when-using-it-with-unboxed-type)

Comment: I would be really interested in a thorough answer to the question, if only to see how long it would have to be. This is really a pretty embarrassing situation...

Answer (score 8):

This is a continuation of @leftaroundabout's answer.

In Haskell, values have types. But types *themselves* also have types. When a type is acting as the type of another type, we call it a "kind".

The most important and common kind in Haskell is [`Type`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type), often denoted in signatures as `*`. It is the kind of types that are "lifted", that is, whose values can be thunks that, when evaluated, can diverge, throw an error, etc... For example the type `Int` has kind `Type`.

There are also other types like [`Int#`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:3) that are *not* lifted. A value of type `Int#` is *never* a thunk, it's always an actual value in memory.

In short, the in-memory representation of values is *controlled* by their type's kind.

[`RuntimeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Types.html#t:RuntimeRep) is another kind. It is the kind of types like `LiftedRep` and `IntRep`. These types don't have any values, they exist merely to [express things at the type level](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=datakinds#extension-DataKinds), as we shall see.

There is a super-magical type-level entity called [`TYPE`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Types.html#t:TYPE) that, when parameterized with a type of kind `RuntimeRep` (that is with a type that describes an in-memory representation) returns the kind of types whose values have that representation. For example, `Type` is `TYPE LiftedRep`, while the kind of `Int#` is `TYPE IntRep`.

```
ghci> :set -XMagicHash
ghci> import GHC.Prim 
ghci> import GHC.Types
ghci> import Data.Kind
ghci> :kind (Int :: TYPE 'LiftedRep)
(Int :: TYPE 'LiftedRep) :: *
ghci> :kind Int#
Int# :: TYPE 'IntRep
```

Now we can get back to why `undefined` has such a weird signature. The thing is, we want to be able to use `undefined` in *all* functions, be it functions that return types of kind `Type`, but also functions that return types of kind `TYPE IntRep` (in other words: the `Int#` type) or functions that return another unlifted type. Otherwise, we would need multiple different versions of `undefined`, which would be annoying.

The solution is to make `undefined` *levity-polymorphic*. The signature says: for any possible in-memory representation (`RuntimeRep`) and for any possible *type* whose values have that representation, `undefined` counts a member of that type.

Comment: what does `Int` in `IntRep` stand for, is it "int" or "internal" (or something else)? i.e. what is the kind of `Double#`, is it `TYPE 'DoubleRep`? is `TYPE 'LiftedRep` in `(Int :: TYPE 'LiftedRep)` the *kind* of `Int`? if not, what is it? thanks.

Comment: @WillNess The `Int` in `IntRep` indeed stands for "integer". The kind of `Double#` is  `TYPE 'DoubleRep`, yes, and the kind of `Int` (and of `Bool` and of `Char`...) is `TYPE 'LiftedRep`. The `TYPE 'LiftedRep` kind usually appears in type signatures as `Type` (or `*`). The GHC User Guide has more information: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#levity-polymorphism