# Understanding the type of ($) operator

Tags: haskell, types

The module [GHC/Base.hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%24) contains the following operator definition:

```hs
($) :: forall r a (b :: TYPE r). (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x =  f x
```

- What does the universally quantified variable `r` mean ?
- Isn't the signature `(a -> b) -> a -> b` sufficiently general ?
- What's `TYPE` ?

Comment: I'm not qualified to write an answer myself, but google-chasing some terminology from the comments before that definition leads to https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/representation_polymorphism.html  (6.4.12.2 makes a specific example of `($)`).

Comment: `TYPE` allows for representation polymorphism. `Type` (formerly known as `*`) is just a type alias for `TYPE LiftedRep`. As you might guess from that example, there are other things (of kind `RuntimeRep`) that you can pass to `TYPE` to get other "kinds" of types. (Kind in quotes just to emphasize that I'm not talking about  kinds in the formal sense.)

Comment: (Above comment is just a rough summary of the first couple of paragraphs in the page hobbs linked to.)

Comment: I realize that "levity" means "liftedness" here, but "levity polymorphism" still reads to me like "it works on funny, punny, serious, and downright unfunny types." :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311510/what-does-type-signature-for-undefined-mean-in-haskell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TYPE` provides support for [representation polymorphism](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/representation_polymorphism.html).

The types you are used to have kind `Type` (formerly known as `*`). But there are other kinds[*] of types. `Type` is just an alias for `TYPE LiftedRep`. We could more formally write the "usual" type for `($)` as

```
($) :: forall (a :: Type) (b :: Type) . (a -> b) -> a -> b
-- ($) :: forall (a :: TYPE LiftedRep) (b :: TYPE LiftedRep) . (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

The introduction of `r` just means that we aren't restricting `b` to "ordinary" types. `b` doesn't have to have kind `TYPE LiftedRep`; it can have kind `TYPE r` for any `r` that is a valid argument to `TYPE`.

---

[*] "kind" in the English sense, not the formal concept called "kind" in Haskell's type system.

Comment: Thank you ! Could you give an example of a type that isn't of kind `TYPE LiftedRep` ?

Comment: @F.Zer The type `Int#`, an unboxed primitive int, has kind `TYPE 'GHC.Types.IntRep`.